# JavaScript hanging writing errors from a .ps1 script

Tags: javascript, powershell, batch-file

Because of reasons, I have a situation in which I need to use a .js file to call a .bat file, which calls a .ps1 file. It may sound crazy, but yes, I have to launch the .ps1 file this way.

My problem is that, the .js file is hanging after writing a variable number of errors. The number of errors that causes the script to hang changes between scripts, but seems to be consistent within a script.

I have included sanitized scripts below.

Every time I run this particular combo using cscript (cscript c:\temp\test.js "c:\temp\test3.bat"), the script stops after writing "Checking device 10 of 100." to the log file and does not return me to the prompt. If I run the .bat file from the same command prompt, the script runs as expected. If, on line 41 of the .ps1 script, I change the message type from "Error" to "Verbose" (for example), the script runs fine and completes as expected.

It seems that the .js file does not like something about "`Write-Error $Message`" from the Out-PsLogging function but:

1. I cannot tell what it doesn't like
2. I cannot tell why it stops writing errors after (in this case) 10 errors

I have seen this behavior on Windows 10 and Server 2019 (ps 5.1).

Code:

```
test.js
var wshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var cmdLine = WScript.Arguments(0);
var result = {};
result.stdout = "";
result.stderr = "";
result.exitCode = -1;

if (!wshShell) {
        WScript.Echo("Can not run command");
    }

    var oExec;
    try {
        oExec = wshShell.Exec(cmdLine);
        WScript.Echo("Ran the command - " + cmdLine);
        WScript.Echo(oExec.Status);

        var line;
        WScript.Echo("About to start while loop");
        while (oExec.Status != 1) {
            WScript.Echo(oExec.Status);
            while (!oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream) {
                WScript.Echo("Inside the second while loop");
                line = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine();
                result.stdout += line + "\n";
                WScript.Echo(line + "\n");
                WScript.Echo(oExec.StdOut.AtEndOfStream);
            }
            while (!oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream) {
                WScript.Echo("Inside the third while loop");
                line = oExec.StdErr.ReadLine();
                result.stderr += line + "\n";
                WScript.Echo(line + "\n");
                WScript.Echo(oExec.StdErr.AtEndOfStream);
            }

            WScript.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    catch (e) {
        WScript.Echo("Unable to run command - " + cmdLine);
        WScript.Echo(e);
    }
```

```
test3.bat
cmd.exe /C Powershell.exe -Command "&{C:\temp\test3.ps1 -Verbose}"
```

```
test3.ps1
Function Out-PsLogging {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'SessionOnly')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'File')]
        [System.IO.FileInfo]$LogPath,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Message,

        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [ValidateSet('Info', 'Warning', 'Error', 'Verbose', 'First')]
        [string]$MessageType
    )

    $logType = "LogFile"

    Switch ($logType) {
        "LogFile" {
            Switch ($MessageType) {
                "Info" { [System.IO.File]::AppendAllLines([string]$LogPath, [string[]]$Message); Write-Host $Message }
                "Warning" { [System.IO.File]::AppendAllLines([string]$LogPath, [string[]]$Message); Write-Warning $Message }
                "Error" { [System.IO.File]::AppendAllLines([string]$LogPath, [string[]]$Message); Write-Error $Message }
                "Verbose" { [System.IO.File]::AppendAllLines([string]$LogPath, [string[]]$Message); Write-Verbose $Message -Verbose }
                "First" { [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($LogPath, $Message); Write-Verbose $Message -Verbose }
            }
        }
    }
}

$a = 0
$array = @(1..100)
$LogPath  = 'C:\temp\log3.txt'

$message = ("{0}: Beginning {1}." -f ([datetime]::Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd`THH:mm:ss"), $myinvocation.MyCommand)
Out-PsLogging -LogPath $LogPath -MessageType First -Message $message

$itGlueConfigsMatchingPolicy = Foreach ($device in $array) {
    $a++

    $message = ("{0}: Checking device {1} of {2}." -f ([datetime]::Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd`THH:mm:ss"), $a, $array.count)
    Out-PsLogging -LogPath $LogPath -MessageType Error -Message $message
}; Remove-Variable a -Force

$message = ("{0}: Completed {1}." -f ([datetime]::Now).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd`THH:mm:ss"), $myinvocation.MyCommand)
Out-PsLogging -LogPath $LogPath -MessageType Verbose -Message $message
```

Comment: Why are you running a batch file, `test3.bat` in an instance of `cmd.exe`, which invokes a new instance of `cmd.exe` to in turn run `powershell.exe` with a script file as a `-Command`? Doesn't just directly using the `-File` option, achieve what you need? e.g. `powershell.exe -File "C:\temp\test3.ps1" -Verbose`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I run it this way because I have to. Do you have any insight into why the .js script is preventing PowerShell from finishing?

Comment: Please explain why you believe that you have to, StackExchangeGuy, because I cannot think of a reason for this, _hence my comment_! I'm not asking you to, not use `test3.bat`, _you made that clear when you posted your question_; what I'm asking is, why are you using `cmd.exe /C Powershell.exe -Command "&{C:\temp\test3.ps1 -Verbose}"` instead of `Powershell.exe -File "C:\temp\test3.ps1" -Verbose`?

Comment: Like @Compo said, it seems ***extremely* useless** to have a whole file that all it does is to start a new cmd instance to start a powershell command to open a file when you can literally do it without the 2 redundancies! Just use the `powershell -file <filepath> -verbose` command to make your life easier!

Comment: Okay, done. Any thoughts about the actual question?

Comment: I think it would help if you posted some example output.  Have you tried debugging the js script?  The only place I see that has a loop with potentially no output, is the `while (oExec.Status != 1) {` loop.  If it's hanging in there, then whatever is supposed to change `oExec.Status` to 1, isn't happening.

Comment: You also seem to be missing two mandatory parameters when you invoke the PS script from the batch file, so either we're not looking at an [mcve], the script is failing, or does PS prompt the user?  Could that be why it's hanging?  My PS foo really sucks, so best I can do is toss some theories out there.

Comment: Also, please post example arguments such that others can reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue is a bug in wscript: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.wsh/kIvQsqxSkSk